# div background color on top ion-content not showing after scroll down

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to create an overlay div with background color on top of ion-content which already have a background color. It worked well if the page height is enough to contain the div.

However when the div content length exceeds the page heights, the selected background color is not showing after the content is scrolled down.

The following is my code.

```
<ion-content style="background-color: blue;>
    <div style="height: 100%; background-color: red;">
        <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio laudantium, magniam fugiat,is distinctio, denter code hereolores similique voluptate nam! Quis, similique. Nostrum, velit.....</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

[This is the output after the content is scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOQLd.png)

Anyone experienced this or know the cause?

Comment: do you want to add to whole page or only on scroll content area ?? .

Comment: actually I want to create an overlay div with a different colour on top for ion-content. Let me edit the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%`. This will make content that is shorter than the page take up the entire page, but will still allow the `div` to grow past 100% height. You might additionally have to set `height: auto` if it's getting changed in some other CSS rules.

Mainly, this should produce the result you want:

```
<ion-content style="background-color: blue;>
    <div style="min-height: 100%; background-color: red;">
        <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio laudantium, magniam fugiat,is distinctio, denter code hereolores similique voluptate nam! Quis, similique. Nostrum, velit.....</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div seems to be only the visible area.
Try this:

```
<ion-content style="background-color: red;">
    <div style="height: 100%;">
        <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio laudantium, magniam fugiat,is distinctio, denter code hereolores similique voluptate nam! Quis, similique. Nostrum, velit.....</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Suraj, sorry for the inaccurate question, actually what I wanted to achieve is to have an overlay div with a different color on top of ion-content. <ion-content> in this case should already have its own color. Will edit the question.